# Why my Python command doesn't work in Windows 10 CMD?

Tags: python, path, windows-10, environment-variables

I have added the `C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\python.exe` path to my system environment variables PATH but still when I run `python` command it opens Windows app store! Why bthis happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Try to set path to Python Directory. Ex: C:\Python27

Comment: Does it work if you run your command using the whole path?

Comment: @PySaad: I used Anaconda to install Python so I don't have Python in the path you mentioned. I also Installed 3.7 version I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the PATH variable should contain 
`C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3` 
not 
`C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\python.exe`